# How to listen to Beats 1 radio outside of available countries?

Tags: apple-music

Beats 1 radio is not available at many countries no matter what country the Apple Music subscription account from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use any VPN for tunnel to any available country for Beats 1 radio.

It seems that requests only to `itsliveradio.apple.com` should be tunneled (so your connection speed would not be affected that much because of VPN).

Example workflow:

- use [TunnelBear](https://www.tunnelbear.com) to tunnel to UK or US
- in its preferences set tunnel to only `itsliveradio.apple.com` url.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your knowledge. Just to add, there is a Chrome (and possibly Firefox) extension called Hola better internet.

This allows you to simply turn it on  and select a country. The country selection should be next to the URL bar